# prolog find all names that appears three times in facts

Tags: prolog

suppose we have facts in prolog:

```
likes(a,games).
likes(a,books).
likes(a,sports).

likes(b,sleep).
likes(b,play).
likes(b,abc).

likes(c,eat).

likes(d,run).
likes(d,play).
```

how do i define a predicate(three_things/1) that recognizes which two people likes three things?
so for this example, i want the outputs given the query three_things(X) to be

```
?- three things(X).
X=a;
X=b.
```

Comment: What did you try? What is not working with that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what you need to give us. After you make a good attempt at doing this yourself and if you still have problems, you can update your question with details of the specific problem and what you have tried to solve it, and include your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we are able to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [bagof/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=bagof/3) binding the third argument with a list with 3 items

```
three_things(X):-
  bagof(1, Activity^likes(X, Activity), [_,_,_]).
```

If you want to account for only distinct Activities for each person, then you should use [setof/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=setof/3) instead:

```
three_things(X):-
  setof(Activity, Activity^likes(X, Activity), [_,_,_]).
```

Comment: ... but that counts three identical facts for `likes/3` as three things!

Comment: @false: you mean if the database is somehow wrong and contains unwanted duplicates ? I'd use setof in that case instead. Updated the answer